# Дата и время создания файла

Tags: android, java

Как можно узнать дату и время создания файла в Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так:

```
Date lastModified = new Date(file.lastModified());
```

Предварительно проверьте, что файл создан: `file.exists()`.

Comment: А что такое Date?
Из какой библиотеки выгружается?

Comment: Это класс пакета java.util, тобишь стандартный